# Dúvidas em renomear arquivos no codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para renomear esse arquivo.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ANH.png

Answer (score 0):

Tem de ir à pasta onde está o ficheiro e é só mudar de nome, depois o `codeblocks` atualiza.